# compare filenames and sizes with partial path

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, string-comparison

My final goal is to sync new files from location X to location Y.

The source path is `/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-5a792a17-de43-4e09-9c99-36e48c6c30aa/datafs`

The destination path is `/mnt/Usb/DataSync`

I want to compare all the files at source path and its subfolders to be exact as the destination,
so for example:

```
/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-5a792a17-de43-4e09-9c99-36e48c6c30aa/datafs/photo/png21.png
```

is the same as

```
/mnt/Usb/DataSync/photo/png21.png
```

So, this example, I want to compare only `photo` directory and its files.

If this is the same filename but different size (the file changed), I want to copy the file from source to destination.

I searched about `glob` and `os.walk` but all solutions are in case the filename is with full path, but I need only partial path. `glob` isn't my solution because it searches only files in the specific directory, and `os.walk` is not my solution because it needs all the path.

My question:

How can I compare if two files are the same filename with partial path (like the example above - 'photo' directory)?

```
def SyncFiles(DstDiskPath):
    SrcDisk = /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-5a792a17-de43-4e09-9c99-36e48c6c30aa/datafs/

    print("[+] Drive OK, syncing")
    for path, CurrentDirectory, files in os.walk(SrcDisk)
        for file in files:
            if (file in DstDiskPath):
                if os.path.getsize((os.path.join(path, file)) != os.path.getsize((os.path.join(path, file))
                    shutil.copy2((os.path.join(path, file), (os.path.join(DstDiskPath, file)))
```

Comment: The code appears to be clipped at `getsiz>`. The operator for inequality in Python is `!=`, not `<>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trim off the part you want to ignore.

```
def SyncFiles(DstDiskPath):
    # Syntax fix, need quotes around path
    SrcDisk = "/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-5a792a17-de43-4e09-9c99-36e48c6c30aa/datafs/"

    print("[+] Drive OK, syncing")
    for path, CurrentDirectory, files in os.walk(SrcDisk)
        # remove starting point prefix from path and replace it with destination
        dstpath = os.path.join(DstDiskPath, path[len(SrcDisk)+1:])
        for file in files:
            # fix: "file in path" checks if the string is a substring
            srcfile = os.path.join(path, file)
            dstfile = os.path.join(dstpath, file)
            if os.path.exists(dstfile):
                if os.path.getsize(srcfile) != os.path.getsize(dstfile):
                    shutil.copy2(srcfile, dstfile)
```

The file size comparison is not a reliable way to check whether a file has changed, though. You probably want to use an existing tool like `rsync` for your backups.